# Can i use "this" in react hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
function AddCustomerService({ route, navigation }) {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')

  dosomething = () => {
    return <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addAlert}></TouchableOpacity>
  }

  addAlert = () => {}
}
```

this is a function component i wrote with react hooks,normally, it is not correct to define an arrow function without declaration key words such as let or var or const in javascript.  But in this case, the "function" dosomething could be compiled correctly and 'this.addAlert' could run correctly too, so how react could run this code since it is a wrong grammer in javascript ? Or is there could be any problems? Thanks very much for any advices~

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "use 'this' in react hooks"? Functional components are instanceless so there is no `this` to use.

Comment: I knew that, but it could  compiled correctly and my process can run correctly while i  use the statement above, i do not know how react could compile this correctly while  this declaration is not correctly in javascript

Comment: I'm just curious what react hook you're trying to use any "this" in?

Comment: i do not  use "this" myself, this case was the code in my process that others wrote before, i just wonder why it could run correctly

Answer (score 1):

`this` [has different values](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) depending on where it is used:

- In a **method**, this refers to the **owner object**.
- **Alone**, this refers to the **global object**.
- In a **function**, this refers to the **global object**.
- In a **function**, in **strict mode**, this is **undefined**.
- In an **event**, this refers to the **element that received the event**.
- Methods like *call()*, and *apply()* can refer this to **any** object.

Personally I wouldn't use `this` in  a function component, but it is mandatory in  a Class component.

Comment: I knew that, but it could  compiled correctly and my process can run correctly while i  use the statement above, i just wana know how react could compile this correctly while  this declaration is not correctly in javascript?

Comment: TL;DR: you should *not* use `this` in a react functional component. Although something compiles, it does not mean it's the correct way to implement it. To understand why this works, you should understand how ReactJS component's rendering works. I personally believe I am not qualified enough to drop an answer on react base engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use this in functional component. This will work.

```js
function AddCustomerService({ route, navigation }) {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState('')

  let dosomething = () => {
    return (<TouchableOpacity onPress={addAlert}></TouchableOpacity>)
  }

  let addAlert = () => {}
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but declaring a function without any declaration key words such as let, const ,var like the method dosomething above could be correct in javascript?

Comment: No you have to define function

Comment: please let me know if it is helpful

Comment: so,like the `dosomething` above, there is no declaration on it, correctly it need to be
`const dosomething = () => {}`, but in my case, even there are not any declarations, the process run correctly too, i just do not know how it could be right since it is a wrong grammar in javascript